# VS Code Pylance - Problem with Module Imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

My IDE was working fine last night. I created a launch.json file for a completely different app in a different directory but have since deleted it.

My code still processes correctly.

My virtual env is the same - all of my installed packages (pandas, numpy, etc) are being recognized by Pylance. The modules I am importing is the problem.

The modules I am trying to import are all .py files, are all in the same directory as the app.py file that I am running, and are functioning correctly, just as they have been.

Several of the modules being imported also import each other, and the problem is taking place in each module as well.

I have tried both uninstalling and reinstalling the Python and Pylance extensions, and restarting my machine and the same problem occurs.

[image: imports]

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the error message of the Pylance prompt? And could you run the codes? Could you please check the `PYTHONPATH` in the a.py? It looks like a `PYTHONPATH` problem, but it's weird because you had said `are all in the same directory as the app.py file that I am running`. this means the parent folder path of a.py has been added to the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: The error is: 'Import "creds" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports'. Is there anything that debug mode disables with Pylance?

Comment: Could you share the structure of your project?

Comment: And what's the result of `sys.path`?

Comment: Have you selected your python interpreter with cmd + shift + p or ctrl + shift + p. Then search for select python interpreter

Answer (score 7):

*My setup is a Ubuntu 22.04.* My interpreter is a python virtual env (**venv**).

Even tough I had used `cmd + shift + p` or `ctrl + shift + p`. Then searched and selected python interpreter multiple times.

The only solution that worked for me was:

- go to **extensions->Pylance.**
  Then on settings **Python>Analysis:Extra Paths** and add the path to my virtual env. site-packages folder (like /path/to/venv/lib/python3.x/site-packages/)

Or

- The same by editing my **settings.json** file adding:

```
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.x/site-packages/"
    ]
```